# directive from shared module is not visible

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-services

Trying to dive into angular 2 having some experience in angular 1 and having some puzzles.

I made one shared module:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }        from '@angular/common';

import { Constants }   from './injectables/constants';
import { Utils } from "./injectables/utils";
import { HighlightDirective } from "./directives/highlight";

@NgModule({
    imports: [ CommonModule ],
    declarations: [ HighlightDirective ],
    providers: [ Constants, Utils ],
    exports: [ HighlightDirective ]
})
export class VCommonModule { }
```

correct me if I'm wrong, but as I understood only directives,pipes and components needs to be exported here? Services(Injectables) could be used straight away after I include this module to imports of my AppModule? So I did that:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { VCommonModule } from './common/module';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

import { AppComponent }   from './faq/components/app';
import { SearchComponent }   from './faq/components/search';
import { ArticleComponent } from "./faq/components/article";
import { TopResultsComponent } from "./faq/components/topResults";
import { AjaxService } from "./faq/injectables/ajaxService";
import './rxjs-operators';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, VCommonModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent, SearchComponent, ArticleComponent, TopResultsComponent ],
    providers: [ AjaxService ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

But when I'm trying to use [highlight] directive in my component insight AppModule it shows me an error

```
zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'highlight' since it isn't a known property of 'span'. ("         <br/>
                <span [innerHTML]="article.Content__c"
                      [ERROR ->][highlight]
                      keywords="test"></span> <!-- [innerHTML]="article.Content__c | "): SearchComponent@39:26 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error:
```

services from VCommonModule seems works fine after I added them as **providers: [ Constants, Utils ]** of my component

```
import {Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer, OnChanges} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: '[highlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective implements OnChanges{
    @Input()
    keywords:string;

    highlightClass: string = 'highLight';

    constructor(
        private elementRef:ElementRef,
        private renderer:Renderer) {
    }

    replacer(match, item) {
        return `<span class="${this.highlightClass}">${match}</span>`;
    }

    tokenize(keywords) {
        keywords = keywords.replace(new RegExp(',$','g'), '').split(',');
        return keywords.map((keyword) => {
            return '\\b'+keyword.replace(new RegExp('^ | $','g'),     '')+'\\b';
        });
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.keywords) {
            var tokenized = this.tokenize(this.keywords);
            var regex = new RegExp(tokenized.join('|'), 'gmi');

            var html =     this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML.replace(regex, (match, item) => {
                return this.replacer(match, item);
            });

            this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement,     'innerHTML', html);
        }
    }
}
```

PS: angular version 2.1.2

Comment: Could you add your `HighlightDirective` class implementation?

Comment: sure mate, done

Comment: Remove the brackets surrounding `highlight` in the template; it should be marked up as a normal attribute.

Comment: Hey cartant...thx. Would you mind to put you suggestion as an answer

Comment: Or you can add `@Input() highlight: any` to your `HighlightDirective`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is not related to the modules; it's the syntax used in the template.

According to the error message, you've used the [one-way binding syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax) - as your `highlight` directive is enclosed in braces:

```
<span ... [highlight] ...></span>
```

In this situation, Angular will attempt to bind to a directive property or to an element property. Your directive has no input property named `highlight` and the `span` element has no `highlight` property, so an error is effected.

If you remove the braces, the issue should be resolved:

```
<span ... highlight ...></span>
```