# Why is directive from shared module undefined?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-module

I'am using in an angular 7 app, a shared module to use a **directive** in different other modules.

```
import { Directive, OnInit, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appServerSuccess]'
})

export class ServerSuccessDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() appServerSuccess: string;
    @HostBinding()
    get innerText() {
       return this.appServerSuccess;
    }
    @HostBinding('class.success')
    get success () {
       return this.appServerSuccess.toLocaleLowerCase().includes('success');
    }

    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

In **shared.module.ts**, I do have an **declaration** and **export** of the directive:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { ServerSuccessDirective } from './directives/server-success.directive';


@NgModule({
    imports: [ ],
    declarations: [ ServerSuccessDirective ],
    exports: [ ServerSuccessDirective ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

In each of **app.module.ts** and in **user.module.ts**, I do have the import of **SharedModule**

The directive is being used in different components in the app.

```
<div [appServerSuccess]="msg"></div>
```

The **msg** is being passed via service as:

```
private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('');
currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

constructor() {
    changeMessage(msg: string) {
        this.messageSource.next( msg );
    }
}
```

in the components in the **app.module**, it works fine, but in other component within **user.module** it throws following error:

> Cannot read property 'toLocaleLowerCase' of undefined

This means that the directive not being recognized in **user.module**.

The **import** in modules, **declaration** and **export** in SharedModule are correct. Where I'am going wrong?

I have been searching, found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412477/directive-from-shared-module-is-not-visible), which looks kind of similar, but it has not the fix for my issue.

Comment: it lloks like this.appServerSuccess is undefined ... maybe can you add a initialize for msg var?

Comment: If directive was not recognized you would have gotten a different error (something like `Cannot bind to "appServerSuccess" since it isn't a known property of "div"`). This means that your error is just that `msg` is not defined at that specific moment when `success` is being accessed...

Comment: @miselking: That's true. But this error message was suddenly  a kind of fixed/gone

Comment: The msg variable is being passed by a service via BehaviorSubject. And I sue it in a http request response. I will update my question to make sure I'am adding all the necessary infos.

Answer (score 3):

default value of initialized **`appServerSuccess`** is `undefined`, so assign a value to it before you passing a value from the Parent Component.

> change this line

```
 @Input() appServerSuccess: string;
```

> to this line

```
 @Input() appServerSuccess: string = '';
```

or any other `string` as default one.

have a look here for more about [**`typescript variables declarations`**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html)

Comment: Did try this, but didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed. It was in the component which belongs to the user.module, and uses/passes the value of **msg** property for the directive.

So e.g. in a component **user-update.component.ts** I had **msg** property which was not initialized like: `msg: string`. I changed this to: `msg = '';`